# Select and modify a random subset of the dataframe's elements

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe structured like this:

```
1 8 9  
6 4 9  
5 4 8
```

**I want to random take 50% data and then change them to 1 in this dataframe.**

Like

```
1 8 9 
6 1 1 
1 4 8
```

I just found `DataFrame.sample` but it looks just can chose row and columns.

Comment: The suggested edit queue is full. I think this question will be of more use to future readers if the title specifies that you want to replace random elements throughout the DataFrame. Needing to select random rows is a more common problem with a built-in solution.

Answer (score 4):

```py
df[np.random.random(df.shape) > .5] = 1
```

`np.random.random(df.shape)` will create an array of random floats between 0 and 1 of the same shape as `df`. Comparing this to `.5` will create a boolean array where True and False are evenly distributed. This can then be used as a mask to set values to 1.

Comment: For the record, I did not downvote the other answer, which has since been deleted.

Comment: @Neither I get it back

Comment: Kindly check the output , I think he need 50% of cell to set as 1

Comment: @BENY I did read the question, this superb answer (IMO) does what it requires.

Comment: @BENY Yes, and this answer does that. The answerer explained the working of it (unlike you); you can read that.

Comment: @BENY Which comment? I only removed the very first one which said "No, you didn't upvote" to you after upvote count moved to 3. And given that you un-upvoted, maybe you should remove that comment of yours.

Comment: @Neither did you rly try the np.random.random(df.shape) > .5 in your end ? is that give your 6 true ?

Comment: @BENY yeah yeah I understand your query. Sometimes it gives 6.

Comment: @Neither yeah yeah , this is the key point why we have this conversation

Comment: @BENY Yes, forgive me I'm not brialliant as you are. But even in this case this answer is way superior than your post because it explains what it does how it does.

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth Sorry for posting a lot here, I stop now and thank you for your insightful answer.

Comment: @Neither This is Q&A site , the answer should answer the question. Clear ? End conversation

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth I'd suggest to use `np.random.choice`: `df[np.random.choice([True, False], df.shape)] = 1` ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks for the suggestion! Though it occurs to me that my solution doesn't actually guarantee a 50/50 distribution of True and False, and I don't believe that your suggestion solves that.

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth no I doesn't change a thing, only avoids the comparison to 0.5

Comment: I understand the point of @BENY (although OP wasn't clear at all on that) and I provided an [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70581768/16343464) for **exact** selection

Answer (score 2):

As I read there was some debate on the **probabilistic**(*) versus **exact** number of cells that are selected, here is a solution to randomly select an **exact** number of cells to modify.

(*) *probabilistic means that **on average**, 50% of the cells will be selected, but it could be that **by chance** there is significantly less or more than the average for a given occurrence.*

It is using `random.sample` to select a fixed number of cells from a flat index of the array. Then [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) to  transform it into indices relative to the original shape of the data. Finally, slicing occurs at the level of the underlying numpy array (only works with homogeneous dtype).

```
import random
import numpy as np

N = df.size//2 # here = 4

idx = np.unravel_index(random.sample(range(df.size), N), df.shape)

df.values[idx] = -1 # using -1 here for clarity
```

Example output, **exactly** 4 cells reproducibly:

```
   A  B  C
0 -1  8  9
1  6 -1 -1
2  5  4 -1
```

###### handling mixed type arrays/dataframes

We just need to create an array of booleans and use `pandas.DataFrame.where`:

```
idx = np.unravel_index(random.sample(range(df.size), N), df.shape)
a = np.zeros(df.shape)
a[idx] = 1
df[a.astype(bool)] = np.nan
df2 = df.mask(a.astype(bool), -1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Is writing over `values` a reliable way modify the data if the DataFrame happens to be heterogenous?

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth no, it requires to have the same dtype. Mixed types wouldn't work either for your solution (for a different reason though). I'll update the answer to show how to handle this case

Comment: This will work ~ :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ss1=pd.Series(df1.to_numpy().flatten())
ss1.loc[ss1.sample(ss1.size//2)]=1
ss1.to_numpy().reshape(df1.shape)
```

out:

```
1 8 9 
6 1 1 
1 4 8
```